# shell script to rename files in folder keeping order

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rename

in a folder I have several files like

```
name_1.txt
name_2.txt
name_12.txt
name_13.txt
```

and I would like to rename them in

```
name_1.txt -> name_1.txt
name_2.txt -> name_2.txt
name_12.txt -> name_3.txt
name_13.txt -> name_4.txt
```

the following code does partially the job, but doesn't keep the order

```
#!/bin/sh
num=1
for file in *.txt; do
       mv "$file" "$(printf "%u" $num).txt"
       let num=$num+1
done
```

Indeed the output is

```
name_1.txt -> 1.txt
name_2.txt -> 4.txt
name_12.txt -> 2.txt
name_13.txt -> 3.txt
```

How to fix name and order? Thanks!

Comment: Your `*.txt` is sorted alphabetically already.  I suppose you could manually list in your script the file names in the order shown above, instead of *.txt.  An important question is, why do you think `name_12.txt` should become `3.txt` (assuming you do)?

Comment: name_2 shoul come after name_1 and before name_13, sorting alphabetically it gives a wrong result...

Comment: Ah, I see.  You're looking at a thirteen there, where I'm stuck on the leading 1.  You want this sorted meaningfully, not alphabetically.  I think the `man ls` page has an option to sort as you wish, to build your file list (instead of *.txt).  Sorry, I'm at work, on a Windows machine, and can't look up the details for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*.txt` expands to `name_12.txt name_13.txt name_1.txt name_2.txt` because that makes most sense to a computer. You will need to sort this to start off with in our human way. The `ls` command can do this nicely with natural sort `ls -v *.txt`.

This means that the code will need to look something like this...

```
#!/bin/sh
num=1
for file in $(ls -v *.txt); do
   mv "$file" "$(printf "%u" $num).txt"
   let num=$num+1
done
```

Comment: Thanks! how can I keep "name_" before the number and extension?

Comment: @gabboshow You can adjust the name you call it. The easiest way to do that would be to change `mv "$file" "$(printf "%u" $num).txt"` to `mv "$file" "name_${num}.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

Add sort -n to the code

```
#!/bin/sh
num=1
for file in $(ls *.txt | sort -n) do
   mv "$file" "$(printf "%u" $num).txt"
   let num=$num+1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can progress in two steps:

1. Rename the files that all the numbers are of the same length:

   ```
   for file in name_?.txt ; do
       if [[ -f ${file/_/_0} ]] ; then
           echo "Can't rename $file: ${file/_/_0} already exists." >&2
           exit 1
       fi
       mv "$file" "${file/_/_0}"
   done
   ```

   This will rename `name_1.txt` to `name_01.txt` etc.

   You can also use `rename` for that, but there are many versions with different syntaxes, e.g.

   ```
   rename _ _0 rename_?.txt
   # or
   rename 's/_/_0/' rename_?.txt
   ```
2. Now you can use the method you already tried.